# Leak in basement

Tags: basement, leak

My basement is leaking underneath the stairs, in the corner wall. We thought it was from the rain. It’s not. Then we thought the laundry tub. It’s not. Now we know it is from the kitchen sink. I rent and don’t wanna call if it’s just a clogged pipe. My husband says thats not possible in that spot, that it has to be a busted pipe. I know nothing about all this. Any advice is greatly appreciated!! [image]

Comment: You rent, so it's on the landlord to fix it, so call.

Answer (score 1):

Your drain system should be a closed system, so any leaks like that are not typically caused by a clogged pipe, unless a clogged pipe is causing something to back up into another plumbing location such as basement bathroom sink, toilet, or the like.  But I assume that there's nothing else in that general area (or above it) that would cause an overflow of a clogged drain system.  I assume you've checked underneath your kitchen sink and confirmed that there is no leakage from the sink area itself that's running into the basement?  If so, then it's time to call the landlord and have them deal with it.